# GruntJS - How to compile only the changed files

Tags: gruntjs

I have a coffee file. If I change it, only that should be compiled

```
watch:

    compile:
        files: ['**.coffee']
        tasks: ['coffee:compile']
        option: 
            nospawn: true


coffee:
    compile: ['*.coffee']               

grunt.event.on 'watch', (action,filepath)->
    grunt.config ['coffee','compile'],filepath
```

This above config is from the https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch
but it doesn't work.

Comment: short answer: you can't atm

Comment: might i suggest using this new language called "javascript"?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different questions here.

**Regarding the question in the title of your question:**
You can't compile only one file if it changed. However, you may reduce the set of matched files in a watch target.

**Regarding the question in the body of your question:**
I suppose that in the folllowing line:

```
files: ['**.coffee']
```

It should be:

```
files: ['**/*.coffee']
// or
files: ['*.coffee']
```

I believe that `**` is a wildcard only for directories which don't work with files.
So, try one of my suggestions.

Comment: it is is **/*.coffee. And I found in the grunt website the config could work for compiled file alone..there is a proposal for event listener..to heard by the other task